# Cant align text/links on múltiple buttons - rookie level

Tags: html, css, button

So here is my first post. Sorry if offends somebody, im just starting into html/css. There is a lot of info-tutorials out there (in addition my english isnt that good enough) but happens that i dont know lot of the basics, so most of the time the info i get fails one way or another.

--The Issue--

Im trying to create 3 buttons/links inside a shadowed pannel:

```css
    .panel1
    {
     width: 640px;         
     height: 40px;
     margin: 50px auto auto auto;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  
     background-color: rgba(0,10,20,0.8);                 
    }

    .botones
    { 
     list-style: none;
     float: left;
     width: 640px;         
     height: auto; 
     background-size: auto;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
     font-family: impact;
     color: yellow;
         
    }

    #panel1
    {
     line-height: 20px;
     padding-left: 50px; 
     padding-right: 10px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     float: left; 
     height:auto;
     width: auto;
        display: block;
     color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="panel1">
     <ul class="botones" id="panel1">
      <li id="panel1"><a href="Index_2.html">ESTRENOS</a></li>
      <li id="panel1"><a href="Index_3.html">LO MAS PEDIDO</a></li>
      <li id="panel1">CONTÁCTENOS</li>
     </ul>
```

Text color (yellow) on "#panel1" neither ".botones" doesn´t applies to links just to "Contactenos" which isn´t a link.

Also feels wrong to arrange/align text using "paading-left" or "padding-right".

Ive checked a video where some guy recomended this:

```
<style type="text/css">
*{
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;   
}

.panel1
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 50px quto auto auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 2px #color;
}

.botones li
{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 192px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #color;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    font-family: whatever;
}

.botones li a
{
    color: #color;
    text-decoration: none;
    etc, etc, etc
}
</style>


<div class="panel1">

    <ul class="botones">

        <li> <a href="#">ESTRENNOS </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">LO MAS PEDIDO </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">CONTACTENOS </a> </li>

</html>
```

The problem is that im trying to do the same thing but using only CSS, and this guy has used Attribute Style into html.

Ive been searching a lot for only CSS design on buttons but can´t find an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: please provide codepen / fiddle.

Comment: So.. you want to change your link color to yellow?

Answer (score 2):

Color(yellow) is applied only to `CONTÁCTENOS`, because it's selected by the the selector `#panel1`.

To Style the links, you would need to use `#panel1 a`, where `a` refers the link. Check the updated answer below.

**Note:** `id` should be unique. Please avoid using same id's for multiple elements.

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 640px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 50px auto auto auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(0, 10, 20, 0.8);
}
.botones {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 640px;
  height: auto;
  background-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: impact;
  color: yellow;
}
#panel1 {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  color: yellow;
}
#panel1 a {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel1">
  <ul class="botones" id="panel1">
    <li id="panel1"><a href="Index_2.html">ESTRENOS</a>
    </li>
    <li id="panel1"><a href="Index_3.html">LO MAS PEDIDO</a>
    </li>
    <li id="panel1">CONTÁCTENOS</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: nice answer, beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But i still have a question. Its ok to align buttons using padding-left and so on? I mean, the tutorial i refered to wasnt using padding at all, he just got the buttons aligned instantly inside the panel.
Also need to ask, when i minimize navigator window mi design gets all messed up. Any hint how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

For the text color on links you need to apply style on anchor tag, like this:

```
.botones a
{     
    color: yellow;
}
```

And in your HTML code, you use same class name as ID's name of list elements, note that ID should be unique, so avoid using ID on multiply elements.

Answer (score 0):

when you remove the a tag it works.

```
  <div class="panel1">
    <ul class="botones" id="panel1">
        <li class="panel1">STRENOS</li>
        <li class="panel1">LO MAS PEDIDO</li>
        <li class="panel1">CONTÁCTENOS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

an id can be used only once so use a class for the panels. classes can be used infinitely.